# Trying to change any value above 45 in an array to 32 and count how many it has changed

Tags: java, arrays

I can't get it to change the numbers or return the correct value for amount of times it changed

many things

```
/*
3 It's common to have to filter out bad information returned from a sensor.
In our case, the sensor returns a body temperature. 
Write a function called HW2C which takes in an array of 
ints (integers corresponding to readings), and sets to 32 all
readings which are greater than 45. The function should return 
the number of items it has changed.
*/

public int HW2C( int [ ]recordings ) {
  int temp = 45;
  int counter = 0 ;

  for(int i = 0; i < recordings.length;  )
  {
      if (recordings[i] >= temp)
      {
         counter = counter + 1;
         recordings[i] = 32;
         i = 1 + 1;
      }

    return counter; 
  }

  return counter; 
}
```

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with Java.

Comment: i have got counter= counter +1; as it runs a loop

Comment: why not move the wrong part `i = 1+1;`  to the incrementing part of the `for` statement, with `i++`?

Comment: `i = 1+1;` . You're setting `i` to 2.  Did you mean to use `i+1`?

Comment: you are always returning immediately from the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return counter` inside `if()` block and `i = 1 + 1` is not giving proper result of counter variable. remove return statement from `for()` loop and update i inside `for` loop,

Like,

```
public int HW2C( int [ ]recordings ) {
     int temp = 45;
     int counter = 0 ; 
     for(int i = 0; i < recordings.length; i++) //i++ is more meaningful here
       { 
         if (recordings[i] >= temp)
           {
              counter++;
              recordings[i]=32;
             //If you increment i here and condition failed, then you will end up with infinite looping
           }
       }

     return counter;  //This will execute after executing entire for loop
   }
```

Comment: thanks for the help when i add the code to the program it stops the program form marking it just a bit confused why now as i had this error before when i was working on it:
https://imgur.com/a/1drgzFw with your code 
how it should run with code:https://imgur.com/a/dnHB6UP